# how send keybord message (template message) in balebot nodejs api

Tags: node.js, bale-messenger

```
var simpletemplate = new SimpleTemplate(generalMessage like textMessage,buttonList,responseType like "Text");
var button = new Button(text like "salam",value like "/hello",1); 
simpleTemplate.addbtn(button); var templateMessage = new
TemplateMessage(simpleTemplate);
```

this sample code but not work

button list??
button ??

addbtn not exist

Comment: You need to be clearer with your question. What are you trying to do ? What is the problem ? [See How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 7):

this is pseudo code and doesn't work
if you want to send template message by bot you can use the below code

```html
const TextMessage = BaleBotPlatform.TextMessage;
const SimpleTemplate = BaleBotPlatform.SimpleTemplate;
const TemplateMessage = BaleBotPlatform.TemplateMessage;
const Button = BaleBotPlatform.ButtonElement;

simpleTemplate = new SimpleTemplate(new TextMessage("hello world"), [new Button("first","first",1),new Button("second","second",1)] , "1")
templateMessage = new TemplateMessage(simpleTemplate)
```

Comment: not work simpleTemplate = new SimpleTemplate(new TextMessage("hello world"), [new Button("first","first",1)] , 1);
                   ^

ReferenceError: simpleTemplate is not defined

Comment: I've checked it again. It's correct.Check your syntax.